# Installing ROracle in Linux: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

Tags: r, linux, oracle, roracle

I am trying to in stall ROracle in a Linux machine. The Oracle client is installed and set up. However, when I try to install ROracle, I am getting error. Steps I have followed so far:

Install the oracle client:

```
oracle-instantclient19.6-sqlplus-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386 
oracle-instantclient19.6-devel-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386
oracle-instantclient19.6-basic-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386
oracle-instantclient19.6-odbc-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386
oracle-instantclient19.6-jdbc-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386
oracle-instantclient19.6-tools-19.6.0.0.0-1.i386
```

Checked if the `libclntsh.so` is linked with `libclntsh.so.11.1`. Set the lib path in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client/lib/
```

Ran the installation script:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args='--with-oci-lib=/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client/lib/ --with-oci- 
inc=/usr/include/oracle/19.6/client' ROracle_1.3-1.tar.gz
```

I am getting the below error:

```
* installing to library ‘/opt/wolf_workspace/R_Libraries’
* installing *source* package ‘ROracle’ ...
** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -I/opt/R/3.3.3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/oracle/19.6/client -I/usr/local/include -fpic -g -O2 -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
gcc -I/opt/R/3.3.3/lib/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/oracle/19.6/client -I/usr/local/include -fpic -g -O2 -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
gcc -shared -L/opt/R/3.3.3/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o ROracle.so rodbi.o rooci.o -L/usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client/lib/ -lclntsh -L/opt/R/3.3.3/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/19.6/client/lib//libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/opt/R/3.3.3/lib/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: ROracle.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘ROracle’
* removing ‘/opt/wolf_workspace/R_Libraries/ROracle’
```

I am trying to set this up on R 3.3.3 and Linux Redhat/Centos 8. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: `i386` is 32bit libraries. You probably need the 64bit ones (x64 or x86_64 in the name I think).

Answer (score 0):

For ROracle only need the Basic (or smaller Basic Light) and the SDK packages.  The others aren't needed.

To echo the existing comment, you most probably need the 64-bit versions, but you have installed the 32-bit versions.

Since you are installing RPM packages (not ZIPs) you don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, since the RPM install does the equivalent for you.

The latest ROracle is on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/roracle-downloads.html not CRAN (due to some CRAN issues)

Answer (score 0):

Same `clntsh` problem here, even with x64 Basic Light and SDK packages.

I was trying `ROracle_1.3-1.1.tar.gz` from CRAN

With `ROracle_1.3-2_R_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz` from Oracle the INSTALL command worked great.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib:...
OCI_LIB=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4

$ R CMD INSTALL ROracle_1.3-2_R_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *binary* package ‘ROracle’ ...
* DONE (ROracle)
```